# How to setup Electron typing/completion in WebStorm 2020.2+?

Tags: types, electron, webstorm, libraries

Is anyone aware of a more up-to-date guide than [this old JetBrains blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/05/getting-started-with-electron-in-webstorm/)? Specifically, I’m trying to configure the code completion and types in WebStorm 2020.2, and the instructions in the "*Configuring code completion*" section don’t seem to work anymore. I can’t find any newer solution/guide online that doesn't reference that old article, and primarily just want WebStorm to properly recognize the Electron types/functions/etc.

[image: WebStorm Settings]

Path for `electron.d.ts` file is `~/node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts`, and its contents look correct from what I can tell.

I've tried changing the Library `Type` to `Debug` and `Release`, neither works - as well as changing the `Framework type` from `Custom` to every other option, with no luck. I also tried another method I found that directly installs `@types/electron`, but that's deprecated and doesn't have the proper contents, so I immediately uninstalled that.

[image: Alternate Route Attempt]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The completion should work out of the box, as type definitions come bundled with recent electron versions (see `node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts`), adding a library is only required if electron is installed globally. So I'd recommend removing both the library and a conflicting `@types/electron` package.

As far as I can see from screenshot, you have problems with other libraries as well (for example, `require()` call and `process` are not resolved though Node.js coding assistance is enabled). Can be a problem with third-party plugins or file types assignments (for example, if `*.ts` and/or `*.d.ts` patterns are assigned to a file type other than **Typescript**, the IDE won’t be able to use typings for types resolving)

Answer (score 0):

This ended up happening ***again***, even after resolving initially using @lena's observations. This time, I tracked it down to the `electron.d.ts` file missing. I ran `npm prune` at some point and it must've gotten rid of that file. Once I restored it in `/node_modules/electron/`, everything worked again.